# shell script within Conda env can't execute mkdir

Tags: bash, shell, miniconda

We are on an Ubuntu system running conda.
Within an environment (python2, pandas, other packages) we are trying to run a shell script that:
1. creates dir (mkdir)
2. runs executables the path to which are in PATH (.bashrc)

Neither of these are working, and I imagine is a config error on our part.

Here are the errors:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘ResultsSparCC/Resamplings2’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘ResultsSparCC/Bootstraps’: No such file or directory
./sparccWrapper.sh: line 31: ResultsSparCC/sparcc.log: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/charlesh/binf/src/sparcc/MakeBootstraps.py", line 9, in <module>
from analysis_methods import permute_w_replacement
  File "/home/binf/src/sparcc/analysis_methods.py", line 7, in <module>
from pandas import DataFrame as DF
    ImportError: No module named pandas
```

However, pandas is installed in the environment:

```
$conda list|grep pandas
pandas                    0.23.1           py27h637b7d7_0
```

Here is a snippet of the offending code in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
////
INPUT_PATH="foo.txt"
OUTPUT_PATH="ResultsSparCC"
///
mkdir  $OUTPUT_PATH/Resamplings2
mkdir  $OUTPUT_PATH/Bootstraps
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Are you expecting your script to create the directory `ResultsSparCC`?

Comment: @ResultsSparCC is right, if $OUTPUT_PATH does not exist either, use `mkdir -p`

Answer (score 0):

The main suggestion is: read the error-message.

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘ResultsSparCC/Resamplings2’: No such file or directory
```

`mkdir` complains that there is no directory `ResultsSparCC` in which it should create `Resamplings2`.

So, if you do `ls -l`, do you see the directory `ResultsSparCC`? Probably not. What happens if you do `mkdir ResultsSparCC/Resamplings2’ by hand?

If you create the directory `ResultsSparCC`, all scripts should work.

Alternatively, use `mkdir -p`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#////
INPUT_PATH="foo.txt"
OUTPUT_PATH="ResultsSparCC"
///
mkdir -p $OUTPUT_PATH/Resamplings2
mkdir -p $OUTPUT_PATH/Bootstraps
```

Comment: Thanks - that fixed problem (silly mistake on my part)